# How to ensure that only one thread of EJB Timer Service executes

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, ejb-timer

I'm trying to convert my simple Quartz Job to an EJB Timer Service Job in JBOSS EAP 6.4.

I'm having an issue that I haven't been able to find a good answer for. I want to run this method once a day at 1 AM.

This is my class.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class JobExecutorService {

    @Schedule(second = "*", minute = "*", hour = "1",persistent = false)
    public void scheduleJobs() throws InterruptedException {
        new ClinicalTrialsDataExtractor().execute();
    }
}
```

I'm getting these errors in the console:

```
16:51:20,002 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 3) JBAS014143: A previous execution of timer [clinicalTrials.clinicalTrials.JobExecutorService ed420447-56b0-4d27-9533-f77e8a80ffbb] is still in progress, skipping this overlapping scheduled execution at: Tue Feb 23 16:51:20 EST 2016 as timer state is IN_TIMEOUT
16:51:21,004 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 4) JBAS014143: A previous execution of timer [clinicalTrials.clinicalTrials.JobExecutorService ed420447-56b0-4d27-9533-f77e8a80ffbb] is still in progress, skipping this overlapping scheduled execution at: Tue Feb 23 16:51:21 EST 2016 as timer state is IN_TIMEOUT
16:51:22,005 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 5) JBAS014143: A previous execution of timer [clinicalTrials.clinicalTrials.JobExecutorService ed420447-56b0-4d27-9533-f77e8a80ffbb] is still in progress, skipping this overlapping scheduled execution at: Tue Feb 23 16:51:22 EST 2016 as timer state is IN_TIMEOUT
16:51:23,004 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 6) JBAS014143: A previous execution of timer [clinicalTrials.clinicalTrials.JobExecutorService ed420447-56b0-4d27-9533-f77e8a80ffbb] is still in progress, skipping this overlapping scheduled execution at: Tue Feb 23 16:51:23 EST 2016 as timer state is IN_TIMEOUT
16:51:24,002 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 7) JBAS014143: A previous execution of timer [clinicalTrials.clinicalTrials.JobExecutorService ed420447-56b0-4d27-9533-f77e8a80ffbb] is still in progress, skipping this overlapping scheduled execution at: Tue Feb 23 16:51:24 EST 2016 as timer state is IN_TIMEOUT
```

What's the simplest way to prevent these threads from trying to spin up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one answered this relatively easy question. The issue came down to an error in my @Schedule annotation. The method was attempting to be fired off for every second, hence the *. The correct method is:

```
@Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "1",persistent = false)
public void scheduleJobs() throws InterruptedException {
        new ClinicalTrialsDataExtractor().execute();
}
```